# How to remove this seam effect

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, bevel

I am working with a shape which was a primitive cube , made into some geometry , but now the problem is that i have 3 modifiers , Mirror , Subsurf and Bevel in this order but i am getting this type of seam effect **Q: How to get rid of this**

[image]

Comment: In the bevel, set "limit method" to "angle"

Comment: So simple  @lemon

Comment: @lemon write that as an awnsere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bevel will add bevel to all edges if not limited.

So to keep flatter parts untouched, limit it to "angle".

[image]